# How to set placeholder for input box in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, placeholder

I'm trying to set placeholder for input box in IE. But it did not work ...

```
<script>
// This adds 'placeholder' to the items listed in the jQuery .support object.
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery.support.placeholder = false;
    test = document.createElement('input');
    if('placeholder' in test) jQuery.support.placeholder = true;
});
// This adds placeholder support to browsers that wouldn't otherwise support it.
$(function() {
    if(!$.support.placeholder) { 
        var active = document.activeElement;
        $(':text').focus(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder')) {
            $(this).val('').removeClass('hasPlaceholder');
            }
        }).blur(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && ($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder'))) {
                $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder')).addClass('hasPlaceholder');
            }   
        });
        $(':text').blur();
        $(active).focus();
        $('form:eq(0)').submit(function () {
            $(':text.hasPlaceholder').val('');
        });
    }
});
```

I'm using jQuery to do this. The first I define "placeholder" and the second I add the placeholder support for browser.

Comment: Can you try with this:
http://dciccale.github.com/placeholder-enhanced/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but if you are using frames to do this, you'll run into a problem with `document.activeElement`.  Try commenting that and the call to `$(active).focus();` out.